# Jest useFakeTimers() doesn't appear to be working correctly in Axios function with setTimeout

Tags: typescript, axios, ts-jest

I have been struggling with this issue for a little bit now. No solutions online seem to be working, but I am sure it is something wrong with my syntax.

I am using `"jest": "28.1.3"`.

Here are the functions I am testing:

```js
export function timeout(ms: number): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// Checks the status API after 1 minute
export async function checkStatusAfterOneMinute(uniqueId: string): Promise<string> {
    await timeout(3600);
    return await makeStatusApiRequest(uniqueId);
}
```

And my test file:

```js
describe('checkStatusAfterOneMinute', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            jest.useFakeTimers();
            jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout');
        });

        afterEach(() => {
            jest.useRealTimers();
        });

        it('returns data when checkStatusAfterOneMinute is called', async (done) => {
            const mock = new MockAdapter(Axios);
            const data = { status: 'Final' } } };
            const finalStatus = 'Final';
            const uniqueId = '2022030411';
            mock.onGet(`url`).reply(200, data);
            jest.advanceTimersByTime(3600);
            const response = await checkStatusAfterOneMinute(uniqueId);
            expect(response).toEqual(finalStatus);
            done();
        });
    });
```

I also configured jest to timeout after 20000 ms.

However, each test run ends with

```
    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 20000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
```

EDIT:

My Jest config in package.json

```json
"jest": {
    "testTimeout": 20000,
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final version of my test that passes:

```
describe('checkStatusAfterOneMinute', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            jest.useFakeTimers();
            jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout');
        });

        afterEach(() => {
            jest.useRealTimers();
        });

        it('returns data when checkStatusAfterOneMinute is called', async (done) => {
            jest.setTimeout(20000);
            const mock = new MockAdapter(Axios);
            const data = { status: 'Final' } } };
            const finalStatus = 'Final';
            const uniqueId = '2022030411';
            mock.onGet(`url`).reply(200, data);
            jest.advanceTimersByTime(3600);
            const response = await checkStatusAfterOneMinute(uniqueId);
            expect(response).toEqual(finalStatus);
            done();
        });
    });
```

Comment: I am still getting timeout errors, unfortunately. I added my jest config to the question above.